# Trigger slidable from button flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I'm using the flutter_slidable package to delete items from a list I have in my app. But I would like to create a button outside of the listview that can trigger these items to display their slidables, but I am unsure how to do this from the documentation provided

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

```
bool isClicked = false;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text(
          'User Cards',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Provider.of<CardBrandProvider>(context, listen: false).clearCardBrand();
                      Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).selectedBrand = null;
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddCard()));
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.card_giftcard,
                          color: Colors.grey[600],
                          size: 28.0,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          size: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black45,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
        elevation: 1.0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          Provider.of<CardProvider>(context, listen: false).cards.isNotEmpty ?
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 26.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Cards',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        isClicked = true;
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Edit',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(129, 2, 2, 1),
                            fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
              :
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(),),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  
                  var card = getCards(context)[index];

                  var id = card.Id;

                  return InkWell(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [

                          Container(
                            child: Slidable(
                              enabled: isClicked,
                              actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                              secondaryActions: <Widget>[

                              IconSlideAction(
                                caption: 'Delete',
                                color: Colors.red,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                onTap: () async {

                                  setState(() {
                                      showSpinner = true;                              
                                  });

                                  try{
                                    
                                    print('$id');
                                    setState(() {
                                      Provider.of<Cards>(context, listen: false).removeIndividualCard(index);
                                    });

                                  } catch(e){
                                    print(e);
                                    setState(() {
                                      showSpinner = true;                              
                                  });
                                  }

                                }),
                                ],

                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text('Username$index'),
                                trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
                              ),

                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 5,
              ),
           ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you need a single button that will enable or disable slidable?

Comment: yeah exactly that - to enable it

Answer (score 0):

make a button and handle:    `Slidable(enabled: false,)`

Comment: already tried this before.. doesn't do anything. If I create a bool and handle it through Slidable(enabled: false) and my button, the slidable does not get triggered. thanks tho

Comment: was it useful? or what exactly you want? you wants to handle slidable functionalities through a button?

Comment: Can please you share your code what you have done so far?

Comment: Added the code. But yeah man it isn't happening for me yet

Comment: have you try this? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                       setstate({ isClicked = true;})
                      },

Comment: or if you handle your state by the provider, make sure you call your is_clicked from the to ChangeNotifier class.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid I've tried all of that but alas with no luck

Comment: I’m trying to achieve the same result! Did you figure it out @James666